# cordova-plugin-barcode-scanner2 failing to build

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have PhoneGap build app I am trying to build. In my `config.xml` I have:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-barcode-scanner2" source="npm" />
```

I use this for a bar code scanner in my app. When I build it the Android version builds just fine and works. When I build the iPhone version I receive this error:

```
Error - Plugin error (you probably need to remove plugin files from your app): Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-barcode-scanner2" via npm Installing "cordova-plugin-barcodescanner" for ios Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert... Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-barcodescanner':Error: Uh oh! "/private/tmp/gimlet/320/1536482/project/cordova/plugins/cordova-plugin-barcodescanner/src/ios/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm" not found! at Object.module.exports.common.copyFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pgb-plugman/node_modules/pgb-cordova-lib/src/plugman/platforms/common.js:38:40) at Object.module.exports.common.copyNewFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pgb-plugman/node_modules/pgb-cordova-lib/src/plugman/platforms/common.js:69:16) at installHelper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pgb-plugman/node_modules/pgb-cordova-lib/src/plugman/platforms/ios.js:54:16) at Object.module.exports.source-file.install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pgb-plugman/node_modules/pgb-cordova-lib/src/plugman/platforms/ios.js:139:13) at installWrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pgb-plugman/node_modules/pgb-cordova-lib/src/platforms/platforms.js:77:32) at Object.ActionStack.process (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pgb-plugman/node_modules/pgb-cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/action-stack.js:68:25) at handleInstall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pgb-plugman/node_modules/pgb-cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:576:20) at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pgb-plugman/node_modules/pgb-cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:368:24 at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pgb-plugman/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54) at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pgb-plugman/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30) Uh oh! "/private/tmp/gimlet/320/1536482/project/cordova/plugins/cordova-plugin-barcodescanner/src/ios/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm" not found!
```

On the PhoneGap frequentley asked quuestions page they refer to this error with this solution:

> The most likely cause for this error is error is that you have
>   included plugin javascript files in your app package, such as
>   barcodescanner.js, GAPlugin.js, cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js, or any other
>   plugin files such as the childbrowser assets directory.
>
> Previously we used pluginstall to install plugins, which would simply
>   overwrite files in your app. However we recently migrated to plugman,
>   which will not overwrite these files and instead fails. So make sure
>   you remove them!

But I searched my entire project and can not find barcodescanner.js

Any ideas?

Comment: the guy who forked the original barcode scanner plugin removed all the ios and windows code and updated the android code, so, bad luck, it's not going to work. File an issue on the issues section of the plugin

Comment: it says under the comments that it supports iPhone....lol

Comment: yeah, he removed the code but didn't change the README.md

Comment: does he plan on adding it back? If not any suggestions for other plugins that work on both Android and iPhone?

Comment: file an issue on the github repo and ask himself. There are a lot of barcode plugins http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=barcode